# Does SonarQube support Java 8 yet?

Tags: java, java-8, sonarqube

With Java 8, executing `gradle sonarRunner` shows this error message. 
(sonarQube version : 4.2.1)

````
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 26721
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source) [asm-all-3.2.jar:5.0_BETA]
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source) [asm-all-3.2.jar:5.0_BETA]
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source) [asm-all-3.2.jar:5.0_BETA]
    at org.sonar.java.bytecode.asm.AsmClassProviderImpl.decoracteAsmClassFromBytecode(AsmClassProviderImpl.java:76) [java-squid-2.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.bytecode.asm.AsmClassProviderImpl.getClass(AsmClassProviderImpl.java:55) [java-squid-2.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.java.bytecode.asm.AsmClassVisitor.visit(AsmClassVisitor.java:52) [java-squid-2.0.jar:na]
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source) [asm-all-3.2.jar:5.0_BETA]
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source) [asm-all-3.2.jar:5.0_BETA]
```
````

Does SonarQube not support Java 8 yet? I would like to know when support is available.

Thank you.

Comment: shouldn't you ask that project's mailing list?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about sonarcube   evolution timeline

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SonarQube [supports](http://www.sonarsource.com/2014/03/29/sonarqube-java-2-1-released/) Java 8 since end of March 2014 (with some [hickups](http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/SonarQube-with-Java8-projects-td5023947.html) at first, which were fixed in version 2.2 of its Java plugin).

I had to uninstall the PMD and Checkstyle plugins in Sonar's update center as those are not ready for Java 8. Sonar's own rule engine Squid should make those plugins redundant anyway.

---

If you are using Gradle 1.11 to call Sonar and want Jacoco to calculate code coverage, you'll have to specify the latest Jacoco version in order to analyze Java 8 bytecode.

Here's my script that does that when called with `gradle test jacocoTestReport sonarRunner`:

```
/** This script is responsible for unit testing and static analysis of the project source code*/

apply plugin: "jacoco"
apply plugin: "sonar-runner"

// Location of the XML unit test and code coverage reports 
def testResultsDir = "$buildDir/test-results/" // Use double quotes. Otherwise the $ won't work

jacoco{
    // Gradle 1.11 ships with a Jacoco version that doesn't support Java 8
    toolVersion = "0.7.0.201403182114"
}
// Call "gradle test jacocoTestReport" to produce a code coverage report at "build/reports/jacoco/test/html/index.html"
test {
    jacoco {
        def coverageReport = new File(testResultsDir, "jacocoTest.exec")
        destinationFile = file(coverageReport)
    }
}

// Let SonarQube analyze the project
sonarRunner {
    sonarProperties {
        property "sonar.projectKey", projectId
        property "sonar.projectName", projectName

        property "sonar.junit.reportsPath", testResultsDir

        // Address of SonarQube server
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://localhost:9000"

        // SonarQube stores the test results in this database
        property "sonar.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true"
        property "sonar.jdbc.driverClassName", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        property "sonar.jdbc.username", "root"
        property "sonar.jdbc.password", sonarDBpassword
    }
}
```

Comment: I upgraded to 2.2.1 thru Update Center, for a java8-project and running: mvn sonar:sonar . Problem still: it does not show any Unit Test Coverage, only a dash where the %'s should be. Any clue?

Comment: @Rop: Do you use Jacoco for code coverage? If yes, make sure you're using a version of Jacoco that supports Java 8.

Comment: I just installed sonarqube-4.3 and did the Update Center upgrade to java-2.2.1.
Anything else I need to do?
Here the jacoco-files I can find in install-dir:
./extensions/plugins/sonar-jacoco-plugin-2.2.1.jar
./lib/bundled-plugins/sonar-jacoco-plugin-2.1.jar
./web/deploy/plugins/jacoco/META-INF/lib/asm-debug-all-5.0.jar
./web/deploy/plugins/jacoco/META-INF/lib/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.0.201403182114.jar
./web/deploy/plugins/jacoco/META-INF/lib/org.jacoco.core-0.7.0.201403182114.jar
./web/deploy/plugins/jacoco/sonar-jacoco-plugin-2.2.1.jar

Comment: @Rop: It's probably best that you start an own question instead of discussing this in the comments.

Comment: Here:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23923443/sonarqube-on-java8-project-gives-jacoco-exception

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 sides to your question:

1. The sonarRunner (client)
2. The SonarQube application (server)

The error you receive comes from the [Java Ecosystem](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Java+Ecosystem) plugins that are downloaded to the client and rely on an old version of ASM (3.2). AFAIK Java 8 support starts with version 5.0. You'll have the same issue with Findbugs and Jacoco.  See also [this discussion](http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/Sonar-Support-for-JDK-8-td5019488.html).

Concerning the SonarQube server, you can start it, but it crashes when you select "Configure widgets", so I would say no, it does not support Java 8 yet.

Answer (score 2):

It will be supported very soon. See http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-386.