# SonarQube on Java8-project gives jacoco-Exception

Tags: java, sonarqube, jacoco, java-8

I just downloaded the latest version, SonarQube 4.3,
then try build a java-8 project with:

```
  mvn clean install
  mvn sonar:sonar
```

That gives me the Exception below.

Googling, I got the impression this is an earlier issue that should have been fixed... ?

http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/Sonar-analyze-Java-1-8-project-Failure-td5023663.html

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-482

Does SonarQube 4.3 support java-8?

Or any clue, what is the problem?

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class java/util/UUID could not be instrumented.
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_6effb9e.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.createFor(ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.java:138)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_6effb9e.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.createFor(ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.java:99)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_6effb9e.PreMain.createRuntime(PreMain.java:55)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_6effb9e.PreMain.premain(PreMain.java:47)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: $jacocoAccess
        at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1690)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_6effb9e.core.runtime.ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.createFor(ModifiedSystemClassRuntime.java:136)
        ... 9 more
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
Exception in thread "main"
```

Comment: For those who use Jenkins, the Java version could be specified there. If it isn't, it takes a default value.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I got the missing info from the SonarQube mailing-list...
To summarize:

To get Java8 maven-build working on SonarQube-4.3:

- Install sonarqube-4.3, and start the server.
- Login to the **web-gui => Settings => Update Center => Plugins Updates => Java => Click "Upgrade to 2.2.1"**

Wait a minute or so for the upgrade to complete... then shutdown+restart sonarqube.
Go back into the Upgrade Center and verify you have plugin: **Java 2.2.1**

- To get code-coverage in Sonar, you now need to build with these commands:

  ```
  mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install 
  mvn sonar:sonar
  ```

Reference: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/JaCoCo+Plugin

That's it.

Comment: I read somewhere there might be issues, if you put all maven-targets in a single mvn-command, 
so if you're using Jenkins, I guess you should put the build-commands in a Freestyle-project with 'Execute shell', 
rather than a Maven-project.

Answer (score 8):

Here with java 11 I had this problem and I fix adding this in my gradle properties:

```
jacoco {
  toolVersion = "0.8.4"
}
```

Comment: upgrade the jacoco plugin to the newest version fixed my problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running jacoco with gradle them update the jacoco to latest version.
I was also facing the similar issues and it got fixed after below changes

Java 11 and Gradle

```
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.4"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error when mvn building a Java 1.7 project using JDK 1.8. The solution was simple: I changed the **jacoco plugin version** to a newer version:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.6.201602180812</version>
```

(The project was using version 0.6.3.201306030806 before.)

Comment: This worked for me.  Similarly I had to bump my version from `0.8.2` to `0.8.2` using jdk8

Answer (score 1):

SonarQube 4.3 embeds Java plugin 2.1 whereas http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-482 has been fixed in version 2.2. So by upgrading the Java plugin to version 2.2.1, this should fix your issue.

Comment: Thanx, it fixed the Exception above. 
Still a problem, though: 
The sonar gui does not show any Unit Test Coverage, only a dash where the %'s should be. Any clue?

Comment: I'm also facing a problem with Java 8 (with SonarQube 4.3 and Java Plugin upgraded to 2.2.1), it's complaining like -- Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Directory contains files belonging to different packages : E:\workspaceCDS\my\package Please fix your sourccode or use sonar.skipPackageDesign=true to continue the analysis.
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.bridges.ResourceIndex.loadSquidFilesAndPackages(ResourceIndex.java:94) But it's not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `$JAVA_HOME` resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue. What we did was re-install sonarqube 4.3 with Java 8 already installed. Then run analysis against sonar. If you already have sonar/java 7 installed previously and have ran analysis against it, sonar seems to install some plugins which causes these failures. If you re-install just sonar and java 8 (dont remove mysql database etc... so history is intact) - re run your analysis it seems to solve the problem with the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the following changes to come out from the problem.I have used the two steps for it , first one is that update the `jacoco` in latest version along with its **`toolVersion`** , please check it once below

```
    classpath "com.dicedmelon.gradle:jacoco-android:0.1.4"
```

And `toolVersion` is as follow

```
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.4"

}
```

Please refer the link for more info [Click here](https://github.com/arturdm/jacoco-android-gradle-plugin)

And now check the second step for it in which we use the `excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']` inside the `testOption` like below

```
 testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            jacoco {
                includeNoLocationClasses = true
                excludes = ['jdk.internal.*']

            }
        }
    }
```

For more info in it, please check the link [Click here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/5184)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem under java 8 and I simply changed the version of jacoco from 0.7.9 to 0.8.2

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this issue when running unit test cases in IntelliJ. My project's version is Java 8 but my IntelliJ is pointed to Java 17.

Pointed my IntelliJ back to Java 8 by changing SDK in
File-> Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> SDK's
and
File -> Settings -> Build, Execution & Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Gradle JVM Dropdown