# sonarqube analyzing on java 9

Tags: sonarqube, java-9

docker sonarqube latest version 6.7.1 broke my maven build on java 9:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project request-work: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar failed: A required class was missing while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar: javax/xml/bind/ValidationEventHandler
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.4.0.905/sonar-maven-plugin-3.4.0.905.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/org/sonarsource/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api/2.10.0.1189/sonar-scanner-api-2.10.0.1189.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/home/jenkins/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] : javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventHandler
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
```

The same configuration on java 8 work perfect.

How to fix it?

Comment: Did you try executing the plugin with args `--add-module java.xml.bind`?

Comment: What's your Maven version and which SonarQube plugins are installed?

Comment: --add-module java.xml.bind is durty hack

Comment: checkstyle-sonar-plugin-3.7.jar
sonar-auth-gitlab-plugin-1.3.0.jar
sonar-city-model-plugin-3.6.1.jar
sonar-css-plugin-3.1.jar
sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.6.0.jar
sonar-gitlab-plugin-2.1.0.jar
sonar-groovy-plugin-1.5.jar
sonar-java-plugin-5.0.1.12818.jar
sonar-javascript-plugin-4.0.0.5862.jar
sonar-jdepend-plugin-1.1.1.jar
sonar-ldap-plugin-2.2.0.608.jar
sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.3.0.869.jar
sonar-sonargraph-integration-2.0.1.jar
sonar-sonargraph-plugin-3.5.jar
sonar-typescript-plugin-1.4.0.1932.jar
sonar-web-plugin-2.5.0.476.jar
sonar-xml-plugin-1.4.3.1027.jar

Comment: maven version 3.5.2

Comment: Any update on this? Did you find a solution?

Comment: Sorry but no, I still use java 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the [SonarQube requirements](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements) page you can read that SonarQube 
only supports Open JDK 8 and Oracle JRE 8. So you need that runtime to run a SonarQube analysis and the SonarQube Website. 
The main problem is the current ElasticSearch engine included in the product (support for Java 9 is added in ElasticSearch 6.2,
see also JIRA item [SONAR-10574](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-10574?jql=text%20~%20elasticsearch%20ORDER%20BY%20created%20DESC)). 
You can read for example in [this](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/03/09/java_release_train_qcon) blog that JDK 9 is obselete so
developers need to migrate the code to JDK 10, JDK 11 (later this year) or fallback to JDK 8. See also 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687957/java-runtime-engine-support-for-sonarqube-7-x) SO question asking for the plans 
for the SonarQube 7.x versions, still without an answer. There is a big chance that support for the next Java runtime will be build into
the 7.x version and not in the 6.x versions. You can analyse Java 9 code. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44002165/does-sonarqube-support-java9)
SO question for the details.

Comment: OK, for some reason SO says that I have to wait 16 minutes before I can provide you the bounty...