# Java Runtime Engine support for SonarQube 7.x

Tags: java, java-8, sonarqube

On the SonarQube [requirements](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements) page you can read that JRE 8 is a requirement and newer Java runtime versions are not supported. Looking at the [Oracle Java SE Support Roadmap](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html) the public update support for version 8 could be stopped on January 2019. Does anyone know how Sonarsource will update their JRE usage (web application, plugins and scanner) in the coming period?

**Update (07-06-2018)**
Jira item SONAR-10574 describes the upgrade of Elasticsearch to 5.6.8 in a 7.x version although looking at the [ElasticSearch release notes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/es-release-notes.html) version 5.6.9 already exists. Support of Java 9 is added in ElasticSearch 6.2 and support for [Java 10 will be added in 6.3](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/does-elasticsearch-support-java-10/134763). See also [this](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-java-9-and-beyond) article in which the ElasticSearch future plans are described. Will SonarQube only support the Java LTS versions?

**Update (19-08-2018)**
Issue SONAR-10574 is removed from Jira. Found [this](https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix#matrix_jvm) support matrix regarding the Java versions supported by ElasticSearch. SonarQube still uses ElasticSearch 5.6.3.

Comment: Have a look at https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-917 and related issues.

Comment: Java 9 has reached end of support...

Comment: The point was what's in the discussions. They are/were waiting for Elasticsearch to support Java 9, and the same seems to be the case for Java 10. https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix#matrix_jvm