# Does the Latest SonarQube Work With Java 11

Tags: java, sonarqube

At the moment we work with SonarQube 6.6. The reason is that something did not work correct with newer versions of SonarQube and they did not want to investigate this.
But it turns out that SonarQube 6.6 only partly works with Java 11. It seems to work, until you want to login. To login in SonarQube you need to use Java 8.
The latest version of SonarQube is 7.4. Would this version of SonarQube work with Java 11? Then maybe we should upgrade and fix the problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [the SonarCube 7.4.  documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/7.4/requirements/requirements/), they clearly state that Java 8 is required to run SonarCube 7.4.

See also:

- [Java Runtime Engine support for SonarQube 7.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687957/java-runtime-engine-support-for-sonarqube-7-x)

which mentions that one roadblock has been a version of ElasticSearch for Java 11.  Another issue seems to be that they were not keen to put effort into supporting Java 9 and 10, given that they were only going to be supported for 6 months each.

Comment: Oops, I should have checked that. :'-( Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the added info. As that links says: support for Java 8 will stop. That is why I asked the question. I look into the information you linked also.

Comment: No.  It says that **free public** support for Java 8 will stop ... if you use Oracle JDK Java 8 for commercial purposes.  If you use OpenJDK, there are a number of organizations who have committed to providing free support.  (Of course, Oracle want you to pay for a support contract!)

Comment: Thanks for the extended explanation. Checked. We use OpenJDK. It seems that this will be supported until 2023. So for the moment being I do not have to worry any-more.